# Задержка анимации блока на CSS 3

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Делаю блок оповещений, он выползает снизу.
Делаю так:

`-webkit-transform:translate(0,0);` (когда надо показать блок)

`-webkit-transform:translate(0,100%);` (когда надо скрыть)

Как мне сначала показать блок, а после 5 сек его скрыть?

*Делал на js, но пришел дядя с форума и сказал что намного лучше сделать все на css.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@-webkit-keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes slideout {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation: slideout 1s ease 3s forwards;
       -moz-animation: slideout 1s ease 3s forwards;
         -o-animation: slideout 1s ease 3s forwards;
            animation: slideout 1s ease 3s forwards;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` - к элементу по окончанию анимации применяется стиль последнего ключевого кадра. Каким будет этот кадр в последовательности анимации зависит от комбинации значений свойств `animation-direction` и `animation-iteration-count` ([see more...](https://webref.ru/css/animation-fill-mode))

Comment: Здесь именно исчезновение, а как сделать именно "выезд"?

Comment: upd: разобрался.

Comment: @W_0rld я просто прочитал `Как мне сначала показать блок, а после 5 сек его скрыть` поэтому и сделал то, что сделал))) ну "выезд" по аналогии. Разобрались - славно

Comment: я так понял не все браузеры понимают команды и для каждого надо писать свою? когда это кончится?

Comment: @W_0rld на самом деле зависит от того, что хочется. Можно смотреть предварительно на http://caniuse.com/ ....... но вообще в наше время это не проблема. т.к. во многих IDE есть автоматическое написание префиксов (так сказать групповое написание/редактирование).... или вообще через `gulp` настраивать, чтоб тот при сборке дописывал префиксы там, где нужно...... так что всё это сейчас легче

Comment: Объясните почему блок так быстро пропадает? Как это исправить?https://jsfiddle.net/qv8rutu3/

Comment: @W_0rld самое простое добавить кадры, в котором будет висеть некоторое время анимация..... то есть... после 5 секунд скрывать...значит установить длительность 10 секунд..... до 50% показ и остановка..... с 50% до 100% исчезновение https://jsfiddle.net/ktwL0zgu/1/

Comment: Спасибо, теперь то что надо!

Comment: Слишком много префиксов...

Comment: @Qwertiy а сколько нужно?

Comment: Я бы вообще поубирал. В крайнем случае оставил только webkit, как последний живой. Хотя и он вроде уже год как не нужен.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так-то я всё, что хотел сказать, сказал в комменте выше http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610637/#comment837675_610640  )))  то есть я то сам хз что нужно, а что нет. Поэтому проще пользоваться тем, что автоматом определит "нужность" и проставит...например задавая параметры в дополнениях в `gulp`

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation Просто на мой взгляд, более короткий код проще воспринимать. Т. е. надо чтобы пример в актуальных браузерах работал, а уж с префиксами и тулами для их расстановки автор как-нибудь сам разберётся :)

Comment: @Qwertiy окай. в следующий раз так сделаю